# sshfs with ansible does not give the same result as running it manually on the host

Tags: ansible, sshfs

I am working on backups for my server. I am using sshfs for this. When wanting to back up a folder the backup server asks for a password. This is what my task (handler) looks like:

```
- name: Mount backup folder
  become: yes
  expect:
    command: "sshfs -o allow_other,default_permissions {{ backup_server.user }}@{{ backup_server.host }}:/ /mnt/backup"
    echo: yes
    responses:
      (.*)password(.*): "{{ backup_server.password }}"
      (.*)Are you sure you want to continue(.*): "yes"
  listen: mount-backup-folder
```

It runs and produces this output:

```
changed: [prod1.com] => {
    "changed": true,
    "cmd": "sshfs -o allow_other,default_permissions user@hostname.com:/ /mnt/backup",
    "delta": "0:00:00.455753",
    "end": "2021-01-26 14:57:34.482440",
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "chdir": null,
            "command": "sshfs -o allow_other,default_permissions user@hostname.com:/ /mnt/backup",        
            "creates": null,
            "echo": true,
            "removes": null,
            "responses": {
                "(.*)Are you sure you want to continue(.*)": "yes",
                "(.*)password(.*)": "password"
            },
            "timeout": 30
        }
    },
    "rc": 0,
    "start": "2021-01-26 14:57:34.026687",
    "stdout": "user@hostname.com's password: ",
    "stdout_lines": [
        "user@hostname.com's password: "
    ]
}
```

But when I go to the server the folder is not synced with the backup server. BUT when I run the command manually:

```
sshfs -o allow_other,default_permissions user@hostname.com:/ /mnt/backup
```

The backup DOES work. Does anybody know how this is possible?

Comment: Have you checked to see if the sshfs process is running after that `expect:` task completes? I bet $1 `expect` explicitly kills it thinking that you are done using the process (I believe there are explicit expect keywords to "disown" the process and allow it to continue running, but it's been a long time since I used expect in anger)

Comment: Yes I suspect the same this. `disown` does not exist (anymore?). I have also tried async poll but with the same result. Async with poll 0 should just keep the process running in the background. I cannot use nohub because of the expect.

Comment: [the fine manual](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/groovy/en/man1/expect.1.html) shows that `disconnect` is the keyword I was thinking of, although it's unclear whether that puts the process just in the "expect background" or it literally will survive `expect`'s exit. I don't have a setup handy to test it :(

Comment: @pynexj I tried the sleep method and the password-stdin method but both gave the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect `sshfs` was killed by `SIGHUP`. I know nothing about Ansible so don't know if it has the official way to ignore `SIGHUP`. As a workaround you can write like this:

```
expect:
  command: bash -c "trap '' HUP; sshfs -o ..."
```

I installed `sshfs` and verified this `bash -c "trap ..."` workaround with [Expect](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/expect/info) <sup>(spawn -ignore HUP ...)</sup> and [sexpect](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) <sup>(spawn -nohup ...)</sup>. I believe it'd also work with Ansible <sup>(seems like its `expect` module uses Python's `pexpect`)</sup>.

Comment: Unfortunately, when using nohub you can no longer use the expect (responses) because it is not running in the same shell

Comment: Wow this worked! Many thanks I was banging my head against the wall.