# sshfs mounts in debug but not otherwise

Tags: ssh, sudo, mount, sshpass

I have a really weird problem where if I try to mount a directory on a remote device using sshfs, I can successfully do so using it in debug mode (when using sshpass), but if I remove that option it will no longer mount the share (unless not using sshpass).  Here's the syntax's I'm using:

[doesn't work]

```
sudo sshpass -f /tmp/pass sshfs -o idmap=user,allow_other,nonempty,ro user@host:/dir /mnt
sshpass -f /tmp/pass sudo sshfs -o idmap=user,allow_other,nonempty,ro user@host:/dir /mnt
sudo sshpass -f /tmp/pass sudo sshfs -o idmap=user,allow_other,nonempty,ro user@host:/dir /mnt
```

[works]

```
sudo sshpass -f /tmp/pass sshfs -o idmap=user,allow_other,nonempty,ro,debug user@host:/dir /mnt
sudo sshfs -o idmap=user,allow_other,nonempty,ro user@host:/dir /mnt
```

If I don't use sshpass command, but just the sshfs call and enter the password from the command line, it also mounts successfully.  Any ideas why this would be the case?  I am totally lost. Thanks!

UPDATE 1

I'm using TinyCore Linux and there is no syslog.  I've also looked to see if I can get ssh to log in general and I can't find any articles saying so. Help here would be appreciated also.

UPDATE 2

If I use '-o loglevel=verbose' I get no output (when not using debug mode).

Comment: see if this works for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65903216/

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that comes across this post, the only solution I could find was to remain in debug mode and background the process:

```
sshpass -f /tmp/pass sshfs -o ... &
```

It's a dirty hack, but the only thing I could find to "resolve" the problem.

Comment: Although `debug` didn't work for me when running in background (`&`), it seems that adding the `-f` (foreground) option to `sshfs` works well with backgrounding via `&`.